# DRI Extensions needed by i965

Tags: xorg, intel

I just installed xorg-server-1.9.1 on LFS-based toolchain with intel driver. Now, when I execute **xinit** to start the X. X getting up but with software acceleration. Whereas I was expecting hardware acceleration to be enabled.
Relevant lines from */var/log/Xorg.0.log* file:

```
[ 77218.239] (--) RandR disabled
[ 77218.326] (EE) AIGLX error: i965 does not export required DRI extension
[ 77218.326] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[ 77218.333] (II) IGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[ 77218.334] (II) IGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[ 77218.335] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[ 77218.346] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on DP1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[ 77218.346] (II) intel(0): Setting screen physical size to 507 x 285
```

Xorg compains that i965 is not exporting required DRI extensions. But I am clueless, **exactly* which DRI extension it is asking.

**UPDATE:**

Post diagnosis, I came to know that *__driDriverGetExtensions_i965()* is undefined symbol in */usr/lib/dri/i965_dri.so*. Hence the above error.

**UPDATE 2**

I recompiled Mesa with i965 option and the problem seems to be solved. Thanks all.